# Silverlight/C# array of events

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am trying to create an array of textblocks.  And I am trying to create a new event for each textblock that is created.  I have no problem creating the array of text blocks however I am not sure how to create a "list" of events to go along with it.  Here is the code I have so far.

```
 List<TextBlock> myList = new List<TextBlock>();

 int octr = 1;

    public void createlabels()
    {

        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();

        tb.Width = 200;
        tb.Height = 60;

        tb.Text = "label";

        Canvas.SetLeft(tb, octr + 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(tb, octr + 100);

        myList.Add(tb);

        myList[octr].MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(mylist_mouseleftbuttondown);

        octr++;
    }

    void mylist_mouseleftbuttondown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)sender;

         tb.Text = "New label";

    }
```

Comment: shouldn't octr be initialized with 0 instead of 1?

Comment: What do you mean by a "List" of events, what is that and why would want it?  In addition to your indexer being off by 1 you also using it to position each new box one pixel to the right and down of the previous, is that you real intention?  On top of that you don't actually appear to be adding the text boxes to the Canvas is that deliberate?

Comment: i missed noticing that! good observation.

Answer (score 2):

is the event getting fired at all?

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Width = 200;
        tb.Height = 60;

        tb.Text = "label";

        Canvas.SetLeft(tb, octr + 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(tb, octr + 100);

        tb.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(mylist_mouseleftbuttondown);

        myList.Add(tb);
```

try this, i believe this must work.

Comment: I can't see why his original code wouldn't work, but yours is the way I would do it.

Comment: I too don't know why his didn't work, may be the list containing objects needs one more level of boxing?

Comment: @Anirudh: You've indicated whats wrong with the orignal code in your comment to the question.  The indexer is off by 1.

Comment: I think that the reason the original code doesn't work is that the event is attached to a TextBlock with an index higher than the index of the textblock just added to the List. For example on the first execution of createlabels() you add a TextBlock to myList and it will occupy position 0. But you octr variable holds value 1 and therefore you attempt to attach event to a TextBlock that occupies position 1 in the List, which I think shouldn't even be there yet.

Comment: I tried to shorten the amount of code I put into the example.  Setting the index to a 1 was a typo on my part.  I also tried initializing the new mousedownevent before I added it to the list and that didn't work either.  I may have to try another approach.  Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.